# Microsoft Graph API Unauthorized Error 401

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am new to MS graph api. I am learning this API and I followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-console and it works fine for me when retrieving the user. here is the code

```
async function main() {
    try {
        // here we get an access token
        const authResponse = await auth.getToken(auth.tokenRequest);
        console.log("get auth reespones ", authResponse)

        const options = {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${authResponse}`
            }
        };
        // call the web API with the access token
        const users = await fetch.callApi(auth.apiConfig.uri, options);

        console.log("get users ", users)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error here",error);
    }
};
```

But I am trying to call other API and **I have a problem accessing the calendar API.**
here is the new function I use to call the calendar api in ms graph.

```
async function getcalendar() {
    try {
        // here we get an access token
        const authResponse = await auth.getToken(auth.tokenRequest);

        const options = {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${authResponse}`,
                Prefer: `outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"`
            }
        }
        // call the web API with the access token
        const users = await fetch.callApi('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar', options);

        console.log("get users ", users)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error is here ",error);
    }
};
```

in my application in azure I already set all the permissions

[image]
I have no idea why it keeps saying unauthorized.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you using personal account?

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma Yes I am ..

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: How do you set the request body?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `Calendars.Read`, `Calendars.ReadWrite` for `Delegated` permission type instead of `Application` type.

`getSchedule` api doesn't support personal Microsoft account.

Comment: I changed already, but it still shows the same error ..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use personal accounts to hit the `me/calendar/getschedule` because this is not supported.

[image]

The [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) works only for work or school accounts or with App token.

As you are using Application context you need to make the call something like below.

`/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/calendar/getSchedule` as there is no meaning for `me` if there is no user involved.

Comment: Hi, I don't use the ```delegated``` one, I use ```application``` but with personal account.

Comment: Now I got it @theboyonfire, use the http call like this `/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/calendar/getSchedule`. `Application` option in permissions is nothing but the app context, which means there is no user involved. Here you cannot use `me` because there is no user :)-

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. But I receives error 404 now when passing https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/8a81f4cd-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/calendar/getSchedule with post method :(

Comment: Are you using, work or school account's userid?